# Process terminated with status 255

Tags: codeblocks

I run Ubuntu to dual boot with Windows 7, I used to work on a C++ project on Windows in VS2013, I imported it to code:: blocks (the original project is in my other partition with Windows on, and I assume I don't have root privileges on it, but I don't really know what I'm talking about). When I try to run my project (which runs fine on Windows) I get the following messages in the "Build log":

```
-------------- Run: Release Win32 in Huffman (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler)---------------

Checking for existence: /media/shoham/BC5461BE54617C50/Users/Administrator.Shoham-PC/workspace/Huffman/Huffman/Huffman
Executing: /media/shoham/BC5461BE54617C50/Users/Administrator.Shoham-PC/workspace/Huffman/Huffman/Huffman  (in /media/shoham/BC5461BE54617C50/Users/Administrator.Shoham-PC/workspace/Huffman/Huffman/.)
Process terminated with status 255 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))
```

Most people on the Internet say to install `xterm` or change the terminal in `Settings->Environment...`, but it doesn't work for me, even though I have `xterm`.
What's weird is that it works on a new project I create on my system to test this. By that I mean this:

```
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

In a new project works.
Do I not have privilleges to my project on my other partition?
Do I have to make a new project copying the files? Or can I link them to be the same one?
What do I have to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I got a similar message too when I compile my C++ code in Code::Blocks IDE. To correct the problem, I changed the default console program to "konsole-e".

Settings->Environment-> Terminal to launch console programs: konsole -e

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs as Code::Blocks is trying to start its default application to run console programs. And since this is an app you've not installed on your local machine it stops and outputs the error

`Process terminated with status 255 (0 minute(s), 0 second(s))`.

Installing xterm could solve this problem if this really is the default app Code::Block is searching for, but there is no need to do so. It is more helpful to look up the current settings and to pick an app that you've already installed.

Go to **Settings > Environment** and you'll find a dropdown saying **Terminal to launch console programs**. Here you can select a different default app to launch console programs in.

In Linux Mint this should be: **gnome-terminal**. In other Linux OS this can be a good choice: **konsole-e**. If none of them work just set up a very simple C++ program such as:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    std::cout << "Hello world! << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and try out different options Code::Blocks successfully opens up a Terminal and displays **Hello world!**.